Langchain and pydantic compatibility
I have gone through previous posts and tried updating langchain and pydantic to respective different compatible versions, however I keep getting the same error message when I do an import :
from langchain.text_splitter import RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter

Error message:

update_field_forward_refs(f, globalns=globalns, localns=localns)
File "C:\Users\RGupta2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pydantic\v1\typing.py", line 520, in update_field_forward_refs
field.type_ = evaluate_forwardref(field.type_, globalns, localns or None)
File "C:\Users\RGupta2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pydantic\v1\typing.py", line 66, in evaluate_forwardref
return cast(Any, type_)._evaluate(globalns, localns, set())
TypeError: ForwardRef._evaluate() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'recursive_guard'

Get an error with recursive guard here. Please advise on what I can do to change this. I have been stuck on it for a long time.
I tried updating the different versions, I tried changing the compatibility to version 1.0 for pydantic as mentioned, I tried updating langchain to latest version, it all fails.

what exactly have you installed? and how did you do it?

Are you using conda or pip?
